# How can I check if a command exists in a shell script?

Tags: shell

I am writing my first shell script. In my script I would like to check if a certain command exists, and if not, install the executable. How would I check if this command exists?

```
if # Check that foobar command doesnt exist
then
    # Now install foobar
fi
```

Comment: Just happened to come across. I think this is the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script , but it gives much more details.

Comment: Also relevant is [How to 'hash -r' and refresh all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398028/56041) and [When to rehash executables in $PATH with bash?](https://superuser.com/q/999439/173513)

Comment: This was not "already answered" because it asks about shell scripts, which minimally means `sh` while the referred question is specific to `bash`.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

In general, that depends on your shell, but if you use bash, zsh, ksh or sh (as provided by dash), the following should work:

```
if ! type "$foobar_command_name" > /dev/null; then
  # install foobar here
fi
```

For a real installation script, you'd probably want to be sure that `type` doesn't return successfully in the case when there is an alias `foobar`. In bash you could do something like this:

```
if ! foobar_loc="$(type -p "$foobar_command_name")" || [[ -z $foobar_loc ]]; then
  # install foobar here
fi
```

Comment: I like this answer.  I tried not to be too swayed by ivants' image which I like even more ;)

Comment: hmm...when I change it to say `if ! type "foo" > /dev/null;` then I get the output on the screen "myscript.sh: line 12: type: foo: not found", however, it still seems to work because when I say `if ! type "ls" > /dev/null;` there is no output and the if statement does not get executed (since it returns true). How can I silence the output when the command doesnt exist?

Comment: Andrew, try `if ! type "foo" > /dev/null 2>&1;`

Comment: `> /dev/null 2>&1` is the same as `&> /dev/null`

Comment: The man page for `type` is very poor on my distro (Arch Linux). The help text is better, albeit only slightly. `type: usage: type [-afptP] name [name ...]
`. The man page shows "options" as "none".

Comment: As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) `hash` maybe the better type especially if you use the command afterwards.

Comment: @sherrellbc `type` is typically a shell builtin, so instead of trying to find a manual among the system manuals open your shell manual, e.g. `man bash` or `man zshbuiltins`, and search for `^ +type `.

Comment: @IvanTarasov, what do I do if I have alias the same name as the program name to add some options automatically? Do I still use `-p` flag? Should I not use it?

Comment: @user9429402 What is your intention here? Check that the alias exists? Or check that the program exists?

Comment: Using `zsh` on a Mac, I had to remove the $ to get it working.

Answer (score 59):

Five ways, 4 for bash and 1 addition for zsh:

- `type foobar &> /dev/null`
- `hash foobar &> /dev/null`
- `command -v foobar &> /dev/null`
- `which foobar &> /dev/null`
- `(( $+commands[foobar] ))` (zsh only)

You can put any of them to your `if` clause. According to my tests (https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/10/11/speed-test-check-the-existence-of-a-command-in-bash-and-zsh/), the 1st and 3rd method are recommended in bash and the 5th method is recommended in zsh in terms of speed.

Comment: [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) specifically advises against using `which`.

Comment: Also `echo =foobar` in zsh. Note that your `zsh` solution only returns true/false, but doesn't print the pathname if existant. Also `echo $commands[foo]` won't return non-zero if `foo` doesn't exist. For a function that works in both shells, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127608/5353461)

Comment: The 5th command returns nothing in `zsh` in macOS Catalina. `zsh` version is `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`

Comment: @Raptor `if` examines exit code.

Comment: the third option seems to be the only one with same behaviour in zsh and bash. For the others, zsh writes to stdout on error while bash writes to stderr.

Comment: `(( $+commands[foobar] ))` doesn't work, for anyone else reading this. Probably why the blog poster recognized it as the "fastest" one to respond. Either way, it seems `echo =cmd` is probably what you want these days, it's a lot easier to use.

Comment: @tubbo `(( $+commands[foobar] ))` works for me. Could you describe a scenario in which it fails?

Answer (score 42):

Try using `type`:

```
type foobar
```

For example:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'

$ type foobar
-bash: type: foobar: not found
```

This is preferable to `which` for a few reasons:

1. The default `which` implementations only support the `-a` option that shows all options, so you have to find an alternative version to support aliases
2. `type` will tell you exactly what you are looking at (be it a Bash function or an alias or a proper binary).
3. `type` doesn't require a subprocess
4. `type` cannot be masked by a binary (for example, on a Linux box, if you create a program called `which` which appears in path before the real `which`, things hit the fan. `type`, on the other hand, is a shell built-in (yes, a subordinate inadvertently did this once).

Comment: Could you put this in the form of an if/else statement (one that doesn't output to the console)?

Comment: And on some custom Linux, there isn't ''which'' command.

Answer (score 31):

The question doesn't specify a shell, so for those using **[fish](http://fishshell.com/)** (friendly interactive shell):

```
if command -v foo > /dev/null
  echo exists
else
  echo does not exist
end
```

For basic POSIX compatibility, we use the `-v` flag which is an alias for `--search` or `-s`.

Comment: doesn't work for aliases

Comment: @Herrgott that's because `command -v/-s` searches in the `$PATH`. Aliases in fish are functions, and functions are searched for in the `$fish_function_path`. Many ways to check if an alias exists, e.g. `if alias | grep -w 'myalias' >/dev/null; echo ok; end`.

Comment: Doesn't this execute the command too?

Comment: @AaronFranke it only searches for the executable, doesn't execute it.

Comment: You can use `--query` and avoid the redirect: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/command.html. While not POSIX-compliant, `command` is built into Fish.

Answer (score 22):

[Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) covers this very well. In any shell script, you're best off running `command -v $command_name` for testing if `$command_name` can be run. In bash you can use `hash $command_name`, which also hashes the result of any path lookup, or `type -P $binary_name` if you only want to see binaries (not functions etc.)

Answer (score 3):

A function which works in both bash and zsh:

```
# Return the first pathname in $PATH for name in $1
function cmd_path () {
  if [[ $ZSH_VERSION ]]; then
    whence -cp "$1" 2> /dev/null
  else  # bash
     type -P "$1"  # No output if not in $PATH
  fi
}
```

Non-zero is returned if the command is not found in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

`which <cmd>`

also see [options `which` supports](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which) for aliases if applicable to your case.

Example

```
$ which foobar
which: no foobar in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/PC Connectivity Solution:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz 2.28/bin:/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG
$ if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "foobar is found in PATH"; else echo "foobar is NOT found in PATH, of course it does not mean it is not installed."; fi
foobar is NOT found in PATH, of course it does not mean it is not installed.
$
```

PS: Note that not everything that's installed may be in PATH. Usually to check whether something is "installed" or not one would use installation related commands relevant to the OS. E.g. `rpm -qa | grep -i "foobar"` for RHEL.

Comment: `which` has other pitfalls as well

Comment: I was just starting to read `man type` to see how it's better.. may be you can save me some time by posting it here.. :)

Comment: The real trouble with `which` is that it is an *external* command, and won't be able to deal with the specifics of the current shell session internals, as it can have no knowledge of them.

Comment: [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) specifically advises against using `which`.

Comment: it's best to not use which here, other answers are safer

Answer (score 1):

A function I have in an install script made for exactly this

```
function assertInstalled() {
    for var in "$@"; do
        if ! which $var &> /dev/null; then
            echo "Install $var!"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}
```

example call:

```
assertInstalled zsh vim wget python pip git cmake fc-cache
```

Comment: heads up: this crashes zsh as is

Comment: would only crash if you are calling this outside a script or sourcing the script.  Change exit 1 to return 1 or some other error code if you are doing so.

Comment: [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) specifically advises against using `which`.

Comment: I used this but changed `which` to `command -v`