# Why doesn't Linux seek the command in all the directories in PATH environment?

Tags: linux, docker

I first install docker through following command from [docker site](https://get.docker.com/builds/):

```
curl -s -O https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.6.1 && chmod +x docker-1.6.1 && sudo mv docker-1.6.1 /usr/local/bin/docker
```

Then I remove the `docker` in `/usr/local/bin` directory.

I install `docker` through `yum` again, this time `docker` is installed in `/usr/bin` directory:

```
[root@dl380gen8snbjbb ~]# ls -lt /usr/bin/docker
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13451927 Apr 20 13:44 /usr/bin/docker
```

When I execute `docker` in command:

```
[root@dl380gen8snbjbb ~]# docker
-bash: /usr/local/bin/docker: No such file or directory
```

but the `/usr/bin` is actually in `PATH`:

```
[root@dl380gen8snbjbb ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Why does the system doesn't seek `docker` command in `/usr/bin` directory?

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn't docker be enabled/started as a service before being used?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/490983/how-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash

Comment: @vmonteco: I think the point is the system doesn't seek all the directories in $PATH.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: Cool! Could you give a detailed answer? I will accept it.

Comment: Maybe `docker` is an alias? Check output of `alias`

Comment: [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639), [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609/55635

> bash does cache the full path to a command. You can verify that the
>   command you are trying to execute is hashed with the type command:
>
> $ type svnsync svnsync is hashed (/usr/local/bin/svnsync)
>
> To clear the entire cache:
>
> $ hash -r
>
> Or just one entry:
>
> $ hash -d svnsync
>
> For additional information, consult help hash and man bash.