# How to change default directory for a command in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, linuxbrew

Firstly, I am new to Linux so excuse me if any terminology is wrong; I'll try to phrase the problem as competently as possible.

I have installed Ruby (`2.4.0`) via Linuxbrew. The `ruby` command works fine; it installed correctly. However, when I try to use the `gem` command (which Ruby should have installed) I receive this error:
`bash: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory`

Now, because I installed this with Linuxbrew I know that this directory isn't correct. For example:

result of `which gem` : `/home/me/.linuxbrew/bin/gem`

result of `which ruby` : `/home/me/.linuxbrew/bin/ruby`

Therefore, it seems `gem` is installed but the `gem` command isn't linked to the correct path. I assume I need to direct the `gem` command to the path of `which gem` as opposed to `/usr/bin/gem` that bash is saying doesn't exist. How would I go about changing this? I tried in vain to change the `bash_profile` but I'm not sure what to do.

Again, excuse me if `ruby` and `gem` are not referred to as commands and if the problem isn't the "default directory" as stated in the title. I wasn't sure how to label it.

EDIT/TL;DR:

Basically, how can I make `gem` execute this: `/home/me/.linuxbrew/bin/gem` instead of looking for the program in `/usr/bin/gem`?

Comment: When you invoke `gem` in a shell, the shell looks for an executable named `gem` in all the directories listed in the PATH environment variable. (`echo $PATH` to see this colon separated list).  For a short term fix, prepend `/home/me/.linuxbrew/bin` to the path with `PATH=/home/me/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639), [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question-

As I had previously installed and uninstalled Ruby via apt-get instead of Linuxbrew in the same Terminal window, Bash was looking for `gem` in `usr/bin` as opposed to the path specified in my `bash_profile` to Linuxbrew.

Therefore, Stian's answer above with `hash -r` would also work, I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `gem`, run `/home/me/.linuxbrew/bin/gem`, i.e. type the full path name (followed by any arguments you may need).

If this becomes too tiresome, you could change your PATH. Prepend your bin directory with

```
PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason you get the error `/usr/bin/gem not found`, is that earlier in the same shell session, the file used to be there. Bash will cache this to speed things up when running the same command many times. Running `hash -r` will clear this.

Editing `PATH` you seem to have managed, hence the `which` command gives the result it does.