# How do I check if openSSH is installed on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, openssh

As the title asks, how can I determine it? Does simply having the ability to use ssh on a Linux machine mean openSSH is installed? I tried `ssh -V` and that gave me a version number, but does that mean openSSH is installed or is the ssh command coming from another tool?

Comment: Do you mean the client, or the daemon?

Comment: I thought openssh was a suite of tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) and [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522712/how-to-check-if-command-exists-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: yes it should mean version number tho i have no idea if that's server or client

Answer (score 21):

When I do `ssh -V` to check the version, I get the following, indicating I do in fact have openssh installed:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

If you don't see `OpenSSH` plus a version number, like I do, then you must not have the `openssh-client` installed, and as you insinuated, you must be getting the `ssh` binary from some other ssh application.

To see all of your packages installed which have `ssh` in them, pipe your `dpkg --list` output to `grep` using this command:

```
dpkg --list | grep ssh
```

...as I have done below. You can see I have `openssh-client`, `openssh-server`, `openssh-sftp-server`, and `ssh-add` installed, all of which are part of OpenSSH:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep ssh
ii  libssh-4:amd64                                        0.6.1-0ubuntu3.3                                                               amd64        tiny C SSH library
ii  libssh2-1:amd64                                       1.4.3-2ubuntu0.1                                                               amd64        SSH2 client-side library
ii  openssh-client                                        1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.13                                                            amd64        secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines
ii  openssh-server                                        1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.13                                                            amd64        secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote machines
ii  openssh-sftp-server                                   1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.13                                                            amd64        secure shell (SSH) sftp server module, for SFTP access from remote machines
ii  python-paramiko                                       1.10.1-1git1build1                                                             all          Make ssh v2 connections with Python (Python 2)
ii  ssh-askpass-gnome                                     1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8                                                             amd64        interactive X program to prompt users for a passphrase for ssh-add
ii  ssh-import-id                                         3.21-0ubuntu1                                                                  all          securely retrieve an SSH public key and install it locally
ii  sshfs                                                 2.5-1ubuntu1                                                                   amd64        filesystem client based on SSH File Transfer Protocol
ii  sshpass                                               1.05-1                                                                         amd64        Non-interactive ssh password authentication
```

Here is a screenshot so you can see the red-colored `ssh` findings:
[image]

Also be aware that OpenSSH consists of a whole bunch of ssh-related binary utilities, NOT just the `ssh` command. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH. Some of them are as follows:

> The OpenSSH suite includes the following command-line utilities and daemons:
>
> - `scp`, a replacement for `rcp`
> - `sftp`, a replacement for `ftp` to copy files between computers
> - `ssh`, a replacement for `rlogin`, `rsh` and `telnet` to allow shell access to a remote machine.
> - `ssh-add` and `ssh-agent`, utilities to ease authentication by holding keys ready and avoid the need to enter passphrases every time they are used
> - `ssh-keygen`, a tool to inspect and generate the RSA, DSA and Elliptic Curve keys that are used for user and host authentication
> - `ssh-keyscan`, which scans a list of hosts and collects their public keys
> - `sshd`, the SSH server daemon

### References:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/423355/how-do-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-on-my-server

Answer (score 5):

**"Does simply having the ability to use ssh on a Linux machine mean openSSH is installed?"**

Answer: No. If you want to connect to a linux machine or server through SSH, the server you want to connect to must have the openssh-server package installed and configured. The computer you're using to connect to the server does not have to have openssh-server installed. It only needs the openssh client.

**You can use Debian's package management system to confirm whether the openssh-server is installed:**

```
sudo apt version openssh-server
```

If you see nothing printed out on the console, then you do not have it installed.

**You can also use the dpkg:**

```
sudo dpkg -l openssh-server
```

Comment: "sudo apt version openssh-server" gives me "E: Invalid operation version" when the second option "sudo dpkg -l openssh-server" works.

Comment: Mine shows this result: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  openssh-server <none>       <none>       (no description available)                                Does it mean I don't have it installed?