# C language, to check if an argument is a shell builtin command

Tags: c, shell

I am trying to write a tiny shell. How can I distinguish that if an input argument is a builtin command (if so, I will fork and execute it)?
PS. I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522712/how-to-check-if-command-exists-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: You're writing a shell, _you_ decide what utilities to implement as builtins (except for the few that are _required_ to be builtins, check the POSIX standard).

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you are writing your own shell, then technically it is up to your implementation what is and isn't a built in command.

**For builtins**

In bash, ksh etc. you can use [compgen -b](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) to generate a list of builtins in corresponding shell.

> -A action
>
> ...
>
> builtin
>
> Names of shell builtin commands. May also be specified as -b.

**For non builtins**

For non-builtins search the path, or refer to [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and search e.g. /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin.

Comment: Thank you. I reread the guide and I think you are right, it is up to me.

Comment: Also take note of @kusalananda, in that the there are certain built-ins that you are required to provide to be POSIX compliant.