# "cmake --version" points to /usr/bin/cmake while "which cmake" points to /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, cmake, path

I am trying to upgrade cmake on my linux computer. Here is the command I used.

Remove the old cmake:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
```

Download and extracted cmake-3.13.3.tar.gz from https://cmake.org/download/

Then in the extracted cmake folder:

```
./bootstrap
make 
sudo make install
```

when I did `cmake --version` it returns

```
bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

which indicates that no cmake executable exists in `/usr/bin`. However when I run `which cmake` it returns

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake
```

And that does exist.

How do I have the command `cmake` point to `/usr/local/bin/cmake`?

My `$PATH` shows

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Edit: different from the other question since I know exactly where the cmake executable is just that `--version` and `which` have different effect.

Comment: Difference between `which` output and actual running the executable by its name means that `cmake` in your case is an **alias**. See e.g. this question on Unix&Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then You need to remove that alias for make `cmake` to refer to its actual location. The question is not specific to `cmake`, and thus it is not about *programming*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639) and [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639) See the discussion of `which` versus `command -v`. Also relevant is [How to 'hash -r' and refresh all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398028/56041) and [When to rehash executables in $PATH with bash?](https://superuser.com/q/999439/173513)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In bash you can use `hash -r` so that it forgets all remembered locations of previously executed commands.

Answer (score 21):

It turns out I need to exit out of shell for the effect to take place. Once I start a new shell terminal cmake --version worked.

Answer (score 7):

Making a symlink in /usr/bin worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/bin/cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [github/cmake readme](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake):

```
 You may use the --prefix=<install_prefix> option to specify a custom installation directory for CMake.
```

In `boostrap` script one can see, that the default cmake prefix installation is, from [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/bootstrap#L218):

```
cmake_default_prefix="/usr/local"
```

But I wouldn't just go with `bootstrap --prefix=/usr`. As I'm using archlinux, I would go with what the Archlinux uses for default installation, from [here](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/cmake):

```
  ./bootstrap --prefix=/usr \
    --mandir=/share/man \
    --docdir=/share/doc/cmake \
    --sphinx-man \
    --system-libs \
    --qt-gui \
    --parallel=$(/usr/bin/getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
```

Looks reasonable. I see you use `apt-get` as your package manager, if that's debian, you can download source packages for cmake from [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/cmake) and find the build command somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

installation starts a new shell; when you type exit after the installation ends, cmake will work.