# A way to specify a command to run if the previous fails

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to trap error (`unknown command`) from the CLI, and do something in the case an error occured ?

To be more precise, I search a way to do something like this:

```sh
if [ previousCommandFails ] ; then
  echo lastCommand >> somewhere.txt
fi
```

Echo is just an example to say that I need to access this lastCommand.

I want it to be a default behaviour in my computer, so the code must be placed somewhere like `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You should check if the command exists before using it with `command -v`. Possible duplicate of [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639), [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution. I don't guarantee that it's a good solution but it may help with your case.

Create a small script which can test the previous command i.e. `test.sh` with content:

`if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  history 1 >> /path/to/failed_commands.txt
fi`

Then set this variable:

`PROMPT_COMMAND+="source /path/to/test.sh"`

> PROMPT_COMMAND If set, the value is executed as a command prior to
>   issuing each primary prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you call *fail*. If it is just returning a non 0 value, I am afraid that you have to explicitely test it after each command, or use a specialized shell <sup>(*)</sup>.

But `trap` can be used to execute a specific command when a signal is received:

```
trap action signal
```

If this is not enough, you will have to get the source of a shell (posix shell or bash) and tweak it for meet you needs...

Comment: I should take a look at `trap`, thanks ! I want it to catch `unknown command` to be more precise.