# Shell script - check if aws-azure-login is installed or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, sh

I'm trying to run .sh script to check if aws-azure-login is installed or not and install it if it's not installed.

any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting here in accordance with [ask]. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522712/how-can-i-check-if-a-command-exists-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score -1):

There is already many commands that let you find packages, such as 'which' and 'find'. You can check using those commands.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).