# How do i verify if a specific package has been installed in nixos?

Tags: nix

I just added `grim` to my system packages in `configuration.nix` and ran `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`.

Now i want to verify it is installed on my system.

Normally i run something like `grim --version` for this. But this doesn't work on NixOS.

What is the equivalent way to check that a specific package has been installed on NixOS?

Comment: Let me get this straight.  The `grim` command doesn't support a `--version` argument and prints `invalid option -- '-'` so you're just looking for some other way to determine that `grim` is on your PATH?  Do you have any other requirements?  If I'm misunderstanding, please post the full output you get from running `grim --version` and also list all of your requirements.

Comment: There isn't really a concept of "installed" in NixOS at all -- and that's a feature, not a bug. Every user account, every shell, every service's process-local PATH can have a different set of software available; you're never obliged to install _anything_ system-wide, and any user can transiently add content to the store for their own use until the next garbage collection run.

Comment: If you want to know if something exists in your current PATH, that's what `command -v grim` is for -- not just in NixOS, everywhere; you shouldn't be using `--version` for that in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522712/how-can-i-check-if-a-command-exists-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: BTW, "doesn't work" is generally pretty useless; we don't know if by "doesn't work on NixOS" you mean there's a wrapper around grim that's breaking, or... well, _any_ other thing it could be. _Always_ show your exact error in the question when asking.

Answer (score 0):

Software you've installed system-wide in NixOS is available in `/run/current-system/sw`.

However, Nix sets up a PATH for each user (each service, each shell, etc as desired) that can have a distinct software loadout; you should always check the PATH to tell what's installed, instead of looking only in any one specific location. `command -v program` will tell you if `program` is found at any location in the PATH, and if so, *which* location.

(This means that even if your system has version A of a program installed system-wide, a given user can choose to install version B instead for their own account; that user will get version B, even if everyone else sees version A).

Thus:

```
if test -x /run/current-system/sw/bin/grim; then
  echo "Grim is in the default shared PATH on this NixOS system" >&2
elif grim_location=$(command -v grim) 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "Grim is available to the current user via $grim_location" >&2
  grim_realpath=$(realpath "$grim_location")
  if [[ $grim_realpath ]] && [[ $grim_realpath != "$grim_location" ]]; then
    echo "...which gets it from $grim_realpath" >&2
  fi
else
  echo "Grim is not available" >&2
fi
```