# error detection in options provided to bash script or from a file

Tags: bash

imagine a command line like:

```
my-script -foo $(no-such-cmd)
```

the `$(no-such-cmd)` is going to going to cause an error, but I can't find a way to let the script know there's an issue. `set -e` doesn't seem to work. is there a way?

This is part of a problem I came across when trying to process arguments from a file.
I was reading a file line by line and trying to detect errors.

here's an example. I've hardcoded in a couple of pretend lines from a file.

```
function err_handler
{
    ehs=1
    echo "bad thing happened"
}

function fxn
{
    echo fxn "$@"
    return 0
}

function doit
{
    ehs=0
    trap err_handler ERR
    eval fxn "$@"
    eval_status=$?
    trap "" ERR

    echo ehs $ehs ev $eval_status
}

line='-x good'
doit $line

line='-x $(no-such-cmd)'
doit $line
```

and the output:

```
> ./line.sh 
fxn -x good
ehs 0 ev 0
./line.sh: line 17: no-such-cmd: command not found
fxn -x
ehs 0 ev 0
```

notice how the error message shows up but the trap didn't trigger nor did the exit status reflect it.

=============== answer to some of the questions asked below ===============

@Barmar - the expansion is happening before doit is called, but it's working because of the doit_init. the errors get caught. I can add this code to the loop in my  real code.

@user1934428 - I'm want to catch any an all errors that come in from the switches I'm reading from a file. This $(no-such-cmd) was just an easy way to demonstrate a hard one to catch.

@charles duffy - I'm not trying to put code in a variable, I'm reading switches/arguments to a command from a file.

@Willian Pursell - I don't have control over input. I need to rely on the users to have quoted the args correctly.

Comment: Not sure it's related, but you should do `eval "fxn $line"` so that it doesn't perform expansions on the value of `$line` before `eval` gets it.

Comment: `doit` doesn't use its parameters, it just uses the global variable `$line`. Why are you passing arguments?

Comment: The error is actually happening on the line `doit $line` because that tries to expand `$(no-such-cmd)`. It's not happening when you call `eval`.

Comment: dang. I've been fooling around with this a lot, and I've messed up the passing of the args. let me put the pieces back in the right order. the main question is still there: how to detect the error in the option

Comment: Always use shellcheck.net when you're debugging a shell script, it will catch these obvious mistakes.

Comment: You're still doing the expansion of `$line` before you call `doit`.

Comment: _to cause an error_ : What exactly do you mean with this? Non-zero exit code? Printing a message to stderr? The command is not found in its path? Please update your question with an exact description of what kind of error(s) you want to trap here.

Comment: If you quote things and do `my-script -foo "$(no-such-cmd)"` then `my-script` can simply throw an error if the argument is null.  If you have errexit enabled (IMO, never a good idea since "`set -e` doesn't seem to work" is a tautology, and you should just write `my-script ... || exit`.  If `my-script` reports an error message (write your error messages to stderr with `echo ... >&2`) and exits non-zero, then you should get 2 lines of error message: a message from the shell about "command-not-found" and a line from my-script complaining that the argument is empty.  Don' overcomplicate this.

Comment: `$(no-such-cmd)` runs before `my-script` is even started. It _isn't_ an argument to the script in any meaningful way.

Comment: As for `doit $line`, that has all the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: (which is to say, if you want a single variable to expand to multiple arguments, you should make that variable an _array_, not a single string).

Comment: You might want to check the command first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522866/3220113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So never call `my-script -foo $(no-such-cmd)`. First do variable assignment, then call the command.

```
if ! arg=$(no-such-cmd); then
   echo "no-such-cmd failed!"
   exit 2
fi
my-script -foo "$arg"
```

Hacking your solution around `eval` and `doit` and `trap err` with interprocess communication between `$(..)` subshell and parent shell will be unmaintainable and unreadable. Anyway, you have to share your `trap ERR` with subshells. And also, you have to do interprocess communicate from the subshell to parent shell - they are separate processes. In the example below a signal is used.

Additionally, below, I have split parsing the command arguments and executing the command in separate stages. Note that variable assignment is equal to the last command executed. In the case of `args=($(no-such-cmd))` the last command executed is `no-such-cmd` in which case the assignment fails with 127 exit code. However, `args=($(no-such-cmd) $(true))` the last command executed is `true`, in which case the first subshell sends SIGUSR1 to the parent shell to communicate about error.

```
#!/bin/bash

err_handler() {
    # Just communicate to parent process that we failed.
    kill -s SIGUSR1 "$parent"
}

fxn() {
    echo fxn "$@"
}

doit_init() {
    trap err_handler ERR
    # just set variable err on SIGUSR1
    trap err=1 SIGUSR1
    # inherit ERR
    set -E
}

doit() {
    echo "+ fxn $*"
    err=0
    local args=()
    parent=$$
    eval "args=($*)"
    ret=$?
    if ((ret)); then
        echo "parsing args failed with $ret"
        return 1
    fi
    if ((err)); then
        echo "any command substitution while expanding arguments failed"
        return 1
    fi
    fxn "${args[@]}"
    ret=$?
    if ((ret)); then
        echo "Calling fxn failed $ret"
        return 1
    fi
}

doit_init

line='-x good'
doit "$line"

# shellcheck disable=SC2016
line='-x $(no-such-cmd)'
doit "$line"

# shellcheck disable=SC2016
line='-x $(no-such-cmd) $(true)'
doit "$line"
```

Execution of the script results in:

```
$ ./script.sh 
+ fxn -x good
fxn -x good
+ fxn -x $(no-such-cmd)
./script.sh: line 30: no-such-cmd: command not found
parsing args failed with 127
+ fxn -x $(no-such-cmd) $(true)
./script.sh: line 30: no-such-cmd: command not found
any command substitution while expanding arguments failed
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck. Do not store command arguments in a string - prefer bash arrays. Prefer quoting command substitution.

Comment: They're getting the arguments dynamically from a file.

Comment: @kamilcuk so there's no way to detect this on the original command line. I figured it was a subprocess issue, but was hoping there was a way.

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr.  Always.  `echo "..." >&2`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over-complicating this.  Consider:

```
$ cat my-script 
#!/bin/sh

if test -z "$2"; then
        echo "$(basename $0): missing argument for option -foo" >&2
        exit 1
fi
echo "$(basename $0) called with argument $2"
$ ./my-script -foo "$(no-such-cmd)" bar
-bash: no-such-cmd: command not found
my-script: missing argument for option -foo
```

This is simplified and I'm not doing any option parsing, but the point should be clear.  The shell communicates to `my-script` that an error occurred by passing the empty string as the parameter.  The shell certainly does know the status returned from `no-such-cmd`, but you are discarding it.  If you want to detect it earlier, you can always do:

```
$ arg="$(no-such-cmd)" && ./my-script -foo "$arg" bar
-bash: no-such-cmd: command not found
$ arg="value" && ./my-script -foo "$arg" bar
my-script called with argument value
```

As with 95% of questions about the shell (I'm making up that statistic, and it's probably low), this is really a question about quoting.  If you fail to quote the command substitution, this does not work because `my-script` does not get an empty string as an argument.  If you apply quotes, the empty string is detectable by `my-script` as a problem.

Since I'm talking about quoting, I will point out that there is no need for it on either of the assignments, and you could just as well write:

```
$ arg=$(no-such-cmd) && ./my-script -foo "$arg" bar
-bash: no-such-cmd: command not found
$ arg=value && ./my-script -foo "$arg" bar
my-script called with argument value
```

but since the timing of word-splitting and the need for quotes seems to be not well understood, best practice suggests using quotes in those places.   General rule: always quote strings that contain values subject to variable and/or command substitution.

In your case, it may be the case that `fxn` does not do a good job of parsing its arguments and does not detect an empty argument as an error.  If so, you need to fix `fxn`.  But if it does parse its arguments properly and generates an error when it sees the empty string, you just need to put double-quotes around the command substitution.

If you are reading those arguments from a file, then the data line that reads `-x $(no-such-cmd)` needs to be changed to be `-x "$(no-such-cmd)"`.  Since you are calling `eval` on these lines of input, you clearly have complete control over them and can make that modification.  If you do not have complete control over that input and you are calling `eval` on them, then the situation is hopeless.  You have joined the dark-side.

Comment: thanks for the advice. the real function would have more error checking. the thoughts on quotes are good.