# How can I find out which shell commands are available in a POSIX compliant Linux system and which ones are not?

Tags: shell, posix

While writing a shell script, I want to try to keep my script as much POSIX-compatible as possible, i.e. any POSIX shell should be able to run it successfully.

While writing scripts, sometimes I have to decide whether I should use the `printf`, `getopt`, etc. commands or not. I don't know how to take such a decision.

Is there a way to find out if a command is guaranteed to be available by the POSIX standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Documentation

**>** POSIX standard Homepage ( [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) )

**>>** Shell & Utilities, in *upper-left* corner ( [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html) )

**>>>** Utilities ( [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) )

#### Programatically

Check this answer: ( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762682/411882) )