# Is `command -v` option required in a POSIX shell? Is posh compliant with POSIX?

Tags: shell, posix

I am using [posh](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/posh) to test my shell script that I want to run successfully on any POSIX compliant shell. While doing so, I found that the `command -v` option is not supported in posh. Neither is `type`.

I understand that `type` is not supported because it is not required by POSIX. This is discussed at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=397601#10.

> "type" is an X/Open extension; note the XSI marking in the POSIX
>   standard.  Since it is not required by POSIX or by debian policy, posh
>   doesn't implement it.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/type.html confirms this. See the `[XSI]` margin code in the synopsis.

But I fail to understand why `command -v` option is not supported in posh.

Some mentions that `command -v` is optional at https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=218530#131.

> And "command -v" is an optional functionality according to
>   http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/
>   just to mention it.

But I am unable to confirm this at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html. Can you see anything here that indicates that `-v` option is optional in `command`?

If not, is `posh` is not compliant with POSIX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on which version of POSIX they're compatible with.  In the POSIX 2004 material, [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html) has the `-v` and `-V` options in an optional part of the standard — the 'User Portability' subset.

POSIX 2008 (as amended in 2013) does not mark any part of the specification of [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) with 'User Portability' subset:

> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> command [-p] command_name [argument...]
>
> command [-p][-v|-V] command_name
> ```
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The `command` utility shall cause the shell to treat the arguments as a simple command, suppressing the shell function lookup that is described in Command Search and Execution, item 1b.
>
> If the `command_name` is the same as the name of one of the special built-in utilities, the special properties in the enumerated list at the beginning of Special Built-In Utilities shall not occur. In every other respect, if `command_name` is not the name of a function, the effect of `command` (with no options) shall be the same as omitting `command`.
>
> When the `-v` or `-V` option is used, the `command` utility shall provide information concerning how a command name is interpreted by the shell.

There are no optional flags listed in the 2008/2013 version.  In the older (2004) standard, the `-v` and `-V` options were part of the 'user portability' subset, not part of the core.

So, if they want to conform to the standard that is more than a decade old, there's no need for `-v` or `-V`; if they want to conform to the current standard (which is more than 5 years old), these options should be supported.

Comment: Thanks. I now have a follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/34572886/1175080.

Answer (score 2):

See the `[UP]` margin code next to the definition of `-v`. Per [the list of margin code notations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap01.html#tag_01_05_01) (emphasis added):

> #### <sup>[UP]</sup> User Portability
>
> The functionality described is optional.
>
> Where applicable, utilities are marked with the UP margin legend in the SYNOPSIS section. Where additional semantics apply to a utility, the material is identified by use of the UP margin legend.

Thus, it's black-letter POSIX: This functionality is optional.

Comment: Only in the 2004 edition — it is not optional in the 2008/2013 edition.  Note the part at the top of the [`command`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/command.html) description which says (in bright red) 'A newer edition of this document exists [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)'.