# How to find out if a command exists in a POSIX compliant manner?

Tags: shell, posix

See the discussion at [Is `command -v` option required in a POSIX shell? Is posh compliant with POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572700/is-command-v-option-required-in-a-posix-shell-is-posh-compliant-with-posix). It describes that `type` as well as `command -v` option is optional in [POSIX.1-2004](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/).

The answer marked correct at [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/1175080) doesn't help either. Just like `type`, `hash` is also marked as XSI in POSIX.1-2004. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/hash.html.

Then what would be a POSIX compliant way to write a shell script to find if a command exists on the system or not?

Comment: How do you want to go about it?  You can look for the command on directories in the current value of `$PATH`; you could look in the directories specified by default for the system PATH (`getconf PATH` — as long as `getconf` exists on PATH).  Which implementation language are you going to use?  (For example: I have a Perl implementation — but Perl is not part of POSIX; is it remotely relevant to you?)  Why not simply try running it?  If you're going to deal with Busybox-based systems, lots of the executables can't be found by searching — they're built into the shell.

Comment: Trying to simply run it sounds like a good approach. If you could post it as an answer, I would accept it and close this question.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate. The answer I saw some time ago is, try to evaluate `hash` of the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: @LoneLearner: It may be that in 2004 there was no posix compliant way to do this, and perhaps thats why they made -V mandatory

Comment: @ChrisBeck `hash` is not mandatory just like `type` is not mandatory in POSIX shell. See the `XSI` margin code in the synopsis: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/hash.html.

Comment: @LoneLearner: yeah you are right, it's not a duplicate, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you want to go about it? You can look for the command on directories in the current value of `$PATH`; you could look in the directories specified by default for the system PATH (`getconf PATH` as long as [`getconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html)
 exists on PATH).

Which implementation language are you going to use? (For example: I have a Perl implementation that does a decent job finding executables on `$PATH` — but Perl is not part of POSIX; is it remotely relevant to you?)

Why not simply try running it? If you're going to deal with [Busybox](https://www.busybox.net/)-based systems, lots of the executables can't be found by searching — they're built into the shell.  The major caveat is if a command does something dangerous when run with no arguments — but very few POSIX commands, if any, do that.  You might also need to determine what command exit statuses indicate that the command is not found versus the command objecting to not being called with appropriate arguments.  And there's little guarantee that all systems will be consistent on that.  It's a fraught process, in case you hadn't gathered.

#### Perl implementation `pathfile`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# @(#)$Id: pathfile.pl,v 3.4 2015/10/16 19:39:23 jleffler Exp $
#
# Which command is executed

# Loosely based on 'which' from Kernighan & Pike "The UNIX Programming Environment"

#use v5.10.0;    # Uses // defined-or operator; not in Perl 5.8.x
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
use Cwd 'realpath';
use File::Basename;

my $arg0 = basename($0, '.pl');
my $usestr = "Usage: $arg0 [-AafhqrsVwx] [-p path] command ...\n";
my $hlpstr = <<EOS;

  -A       Absolute pathname (determined by realpath)
  -a       Print all possible matches
  -f       Print names of files (as opposed to symlinks, directories, etc)
  -h       Print this help message and exit
  -q       Quiet mode (don't print messages about files not found)
  -r       Print names of files that are readable
  -s       Print names of files that are not empty
  -V       Print version information and exit
  -w       Print names of files that are writable
  -x       Print names of files that are executable
  -p path  Use PATH
EOS

sub usage
{
    print STDERR $usestr;
    exit 1;
}

sub help
{
    print $usestr;
    print $hlpstr;
    exit 0;
}

sub version
{
    my $version = 'PATHFILE Version $Revision: 3.4 $ ($Date: 2015/10/16 19:39:23 $)';
    # Beware of RCS hacking at RCS keywords!
    # Convert date field to ISO 8601 (ISO 9075) notation
    $version =~ s%\$(Date:) (\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \$%\$$1 $2-$3-$4 $5 \$%go;
    # Remove keywords
    $version =~ s/\$([A-Z][a-z]+|RCSfile): ([^\$]+) \$/$2/go;
    print "$version\n";
    exit 0;
}

my %opts;
usage   unless getopts('AafhqrsVwxp:', \%opts);
version if ($opts{V});
help    if ($opts{h});
usage   unless scalar(@ARGV);

# Establish test and generate test subroutine.
my $chk = 0;
my $test = "-x";
my $optlist = "";
foreach my $opt ('f', 'r', 's', 'w', 'x')
{
    if ($opts{$opt})
    {
        $chk++;
        $test = "-$opt";
        $optlist .= " -$opt";
    }
}
if ($chk > 1)
{
    $optlist =~ s/^ //;
    $optlist =~ s/ /, /g;
    print STDERR "$arg0: mutually exclusive arguments ($optlist) given\n";
    usage;
}
my $chk_ref = eval "sub { my(\$cmd) = \@_; return -f \$cmd && $test \$cmd; }";

my @PATHDIRS;
my %pathdirs;
my $path = defined($opts{p}) ? $opts{p} : $ENV{PATH};
#foreach my $element (split /:/, $opts{p} // $ENV{PATH})
foreach my $element (split /:/, $path)
{
    $element = "." if $element eq "";
    push @PATHDIRS, $element if $pathdirs{$element}++ == 0;
}

my $estat = 0;
CMD:
foreach my $cmd (@ARGV)
{
    if ($cmd =~ m%/%)
    {
        if (&$chk_ref($cmd))
        {
            print "$cmd\n" unless $opts{q};
            next CMD;
        }
        print STDERR "$arg0: $cmd: not found\n" unless $opts{q};
        $estat = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        my $found = 0;
        foreach my $directory (@PATHDIRS)
        {
            my $file = "$directory/$cmd";
            if (&$chk_ref($file))
            {
                $file = realpath($file) if $opts{A};
                print "$file\n" unless $opts{q};
                next CMD unless defined($opts{a});
                $found = 1;
            }
        }
        print STDERR "$arg0: $cmd: not found\n" unless $found || $opts{q};
        $estat = 1;
    }
}

exit $estat;
```

Comment: Why not use `which` command to determine the path; it outputs null, if no such path exits under PATH, right?

Comment: @jamo We know what `which` does but this question was specifically about a solution that would work on any POSIX compliant system and POSIX compliant shell. The `which` command is not defined in [POSIX's set of utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html).